# How to make all activities in android project move

Tags: android, android-event

I already created my activities but when I run the application it doesnt move when I touch d screen nothing happen meanwhile their are things below that I have to scroll down to see them any help.

Answer (score 1):

Its not clear but i think you want a scroll. In that case you should use the ScrollView widget.

```
<ScrollView>
   ... content that will be affected by the scroll if needed ...
</ScrollView>
```